# Is there a way for screen readers to NOT read type of HTML element?

Tags: html, screen-readers

As the title states, I wonder whether there is a HTML attribute that can be added to an element so a screen reader won't read the type of the element e.g. for

```
<h4>Subtitle</h4>
```

a screen reader would read "Subtitle. Heading 4"

Any feedback appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I imagine that's up to the configuration of the screen reader rather than something the HTML can affect.

Comment: Why do you want that? It would break the expectation of the one using the screenreader. If one is using a screen-reader you are used to how it promotes certain elements, so why do you want to mess around with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to write content that screen readers will ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672156/is-there-a-way-to-write-content-that-screen-readers-will-ignore)

Comment: Otherwise there is this guide: [HTML Accessability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML). Anything else is intended by the screen reader and people are used to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Avoid screen Reader reading out element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872358/how-to-avoid-screen-reader-reading-out-element-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it but I would caution against it.

You can use [`role="presentation"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#presentation) or [`role="none"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#none).  They do the same thing and are interchangeable.  The original ARIA spec just had "presentation" but [there was some confusion](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role-none-note-none) from developers on what "presentation" meant so the spec added "none" as an alias for "presentation".

```
<h4 role="presentation">Subtitle</h4>
```

Adding `role="presentation"` would be analogous to having

```
<div>Subtitle</div>
```

You lose all the semantic benefits of using an `<h4>`.  A screen reader user will not be able to navigate to the text using the <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>4</kbd> screen reader keyboard shortcut (for NVDA and JAWS).  Nor will they see the text listed if they bring up a dialog that shows all the headings on the page.

Presumably the code is using `<h4>` for a reason.  Is that reason just to get the styling of what an h4 looks like?  If so, then I can *maybe* see using `role="presentation"`.  But a better solution in that case is just use a `<div>` and point it to the same CSS class that the `<h4>` uses to get the styling (if you have a custom h4 CSS class).  If you're using the default browser styling for an h4, then using a real h4 and turning off the semantics might be the best way to achieve that.